# Honor escapes in unquoted fields when reading CSVs with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

As far as I am able to see, Apache Spark’s CSV reader will honor escapes only inside quoted fields.  To illustrate,

```py
import textwrap

csv = sc.parallelize(
    textwrap.dedent(
        '''\
        foo1,bar1,baz1
        hello\\, foo2,bar2,baz2
        '''
    ).split('\n')[:-1] # Drop trailing newline.
)

df = spark.read.csv(
    csv,
    schema='foo string, bar string, baz string',
    sep=',',
    quote='"',
    escape='\\',
)
```

will read as

```
+------+-----+----+
|   foo|  bar| baz|
+------+-----+----+
|  foo1| bar1|baz1|
|hello\| foo2|bar2|
+------+-----+----+
```

instead of

```
+-----------+----+----+
|        foo| bar| baz|
+-----------+----+----+
|       foo1|bar1|baz1|
|hello, foo2|bar2|baz2|
+-----------+----+----+
```

Apache Spark uses the uniVocity CSV parser, for which this behavior is controlled by [CsvParserSettings.setEscapeUnquotedValues](https://javadoc.io/static/com.univocity/univocity-parsers/2.9.1/com/univocity/parsers/csv/CsvParserSettings.html#setEscapeUnquotedValues-boolean-).  Is there any way to enable this without implementing one’s own reader?

(I am aware that I can use [SparkContext.textFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#textFile-java.lang.String-int-) or [SparkContext.wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-) and roll out my own parser, but I found this to be rather slow.)